# VBA Updating Dates in Pivot Tables

Tags: excel, vba

I currently have a workbook with raw data that is converted to pivot tables for analysis. This data needs to be truncated down to specific date ranges. I am attempting to semi-automate the update as some sheets are hidden but keep getting an error

---

```
Dim PVTCombo As Worksheet, PVTFull As Worksheet, PVTOnly As Worksheet
Dim ExtDue As PivotField, Table1 As PivotTable
Dim StartDate As String, EndDate As String

Set PVTCombo = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PVT - Combined")
Set Table1 = PVTCombo.PivotTables("PivotTable1")
Set ExtDue = Table1.PivotFields("External Due")

StartDate = InputBox("Please input start date mm/dd/yyyy", "Start Date")
EndDate = InputBox("Please input end date mm/dd/yyyy", "End Date")

ExtDue.ClearAllFilters
ExtDue.Add2 Type:=xlDateBetween, Value1:=StartDate, Value2:=EndDate

ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll
Calculate
```

---

I receive the following error for line 10
"Object doesn't support this property or method"

I have tried ***.Add*** , ***.Add2*** , and using ***FilterType*** vs ***Type***
I have also tried hard-coding Value1 and Value2 instead of the input variables

Comment: Because it's [`PivotFilters.Add`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.pivotfilters.add) or `.Add2` and `ExtDue` is a `PivotField`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ExtDue` is a `PivotField`. The error message is straightfoward: there is no `Add` or `Add2` method for a `PivotField`. You're looking for [`PivotFilters.Add`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.pivotfilters.add) or the similar `.Add2`.

```
ExtDue.PivotFilters.Add2 Type:=xlDateBetween, Value1:=StartDate, Value2:=EndDate
```